# Ansible - Create GCE node with fixed IP

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, ansible, libcloud

I want to create a GCE node with ansible and attach it a fixed IP. My problem is ansible doesn't seem to purpose this option.

After googling and searching in source code, I can't find where is the code which deploy instances.

If anyone has an idea ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's mine :D
And it's a really old and unsed version of ansible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find it in ansible's source because it is in [ansible-modules-core](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/cloud/google/gce.py).

After make a voluntary error with a bad zone, I had this traceback:

```
$ ansible-playbook create_vm.yml  -i inventory/
PLAY [Create instance(s)] *****************************************************

TASK: [Launch instances] ******************************************************
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zulu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1418774247.2-93981074391261/gce", line 2131, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/zulu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1418774247.2-93981074391261/gce", line 458, in main
    module, gce, inames)
  File "/home/zulu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1418774247.2-93981074391261/gce", line 278, in create_instances
    lc_machine_type = gce.ex_get_size(machine_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 2240, in ex_get_size
    zone = self.ex_get_zone(zone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 2333, in ex_get_zone
    if name.startswith('https://'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

In fact, tasks were launched by the temporary script `/home/zulu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1418774247.2-93981074391261/gce` and after searched for it in my local source code, I found it !

The code I searched is originally stored in a the git submodule: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/modules

I've made a pull request for add `external_ips` option: [PR #539](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/539)